# IR emitter and PWM output

Tags: infrared, pwm

I have been using FRDM_KL46Z development board to do some IR communication experiment. Right now, I got two PWM outputs with same setting (50% duty cycle, 38 kHz) had different voltage levels. When both were idle, one was 1.56V, but another was 3.30V. When the outputs were used to power the same IR emitter, the voltages were changed to 1.13V and 2.29V.

And why couldn't I use one PWM output to power two IR emitters at the same time? When I tried to do this, it seemed that the frequency was changed, so two IR receivers could not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in freescale, but how are you controlling your pwm? I'm guessing each pwm comes from a separate timer, maybe they are set up differently. Like one is in 16 bit mode (the 3.3V) and the other in 32 (1.56v) in that case even if they have the same limit in the counter `((2^17 - 1) / 2)` would be 50% duty cycle of a 16 bit timer. But in a 32 bit, that same value would only be 25% duty so, one output would be ~1/2 the voltage of the other. SO I suggest checking the timer setup.

The reason the voltage changed is because the IR emmiters were loading the circuit. In an ideal situation this wouldn't happen, but if a source is giving too much current the voltage usually drops a bit.